# Docker internals using IP address from the user’s IP address pool

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

```
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
OS VERSION : Centos 7
```

Problem statement : -

I have a master machine and a worker machine on the same LAN. Both are connected by the docker-machine utility. The worker machine is expected to run 3 zookeeper standalone containers. I have created a docker overlay network, on my master machine, using -

`docker network create --attachable --subnet 200.184.152.0/24 --gateway 200.184.152.254 --driver overlay my network`

I want to bind zookeeper container with fixed IP address as follows : -

`zoo1 : 200.184.152.2
zoo2:  200.184.152.3
zoo3:  200.184.152.4`

After moving to the shell of the worker machine by using the command :

`eval $(docker-machine env worker-1)`

I run zookeeper’s first instance`zoo1: 200.184.152.2`. It successfully runs.
Then I try to run second Zookeeper instance `zoo2: 200.184.152.3`, but it fails to give a network error.

Then I inspect the network using docker network inspect my-network on worker machine and in the containers section it shows the results : -

```
"Containers": {
            "1a2471c777c907dc05bb0f23e819919354669de699f862e4fdc093293d145b31": {
                "Name": "zoo1",
                "EndpointID": "8bb5eebd1cacf36dc7cdad7fc3d72c45047c66b455c568cc9e8911d2121fd8d6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c8:b8:98:02",
                "IPv4Address": "200.184.152.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-my-network": {
                "Name": "my-network-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "8f747b26e921ee1543631b758b7dfaf8c7e820c47a95849608dc3568f9957e79",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c8:b8:98:03",
                "IPv4Address": "200.184.152.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

This lb-my-network is using IP address required by my components, because of this the entire automatic deployment fails. The worst is, the IP address of lb-my-network changes it keeps clashing with IP address of other containers.

Is this expected? If yes, then how can I deploy a number of containers using automation when docker is using IP addresses randomly from the pool reserved by user’s logic.

In the documentation, it is stated that the docker needs three address for it’s working, a network address, a broadcast address, and a gateway address, so 253 addresses can be used by the user in /24 subnet. But here the lb-my-network is using IP address from the pool being expected to be used by user’s containers.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: may i know why do you want to bind zookeeper container with fixed IP address?

Comment: @Siyu, Actually I don't specifically want to run zookeeper by binding an IP address. It works when I just don't bind address and connect them via there hostname like zoo1,zoo2,zoo3. But there is Kafka cluster running which connects to this zookeeper ensemble and every time one of the zoo services goes down and come back online it's IP address change and Kafka cluster doesn't connect. Binding IP address works. Moreover, there are other components in the system that cannot run via docker hostname technique, for example, Redis cluster, it does not work with hostname but only specific IP address.

Comment: Don't know much in this area, but I suppose "lb-my-network" won't change afterward, maybe you can just avoid that ip?

Comment: @Siyu, the ip taken by "lb-my-network" isn't constant. Suppose, after running zoo1 container, I see what IP is of "lb-my-network", then I run zoo2,zoo3 at different IP's. All fine, but when I take down these three zoo instances, and start them again, the "lb-my-network" will have a new different IP address and I would have to reconfigure my scripts/configurations files of the complete tech stack, and this can happen with other components in the system too, which means I will be spending more time in changing configurations than actually running the system. Thanks for your support and time.